# php fopen() No such file or directory for file created in same process using Symfony/Component/Process class

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3, process, fopen

I am trying to make mysqldump backup and upload that backup to aws s3. everything is working separately but when trying both in a single script then the file is not found by fopen even file_exists is not able to read the file.
please, someone, help.
here is the code

```
function db_backup($db)
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $DBUSER = env('DB_USERNAME');
    $DBPASSWD = env('DB_PASSWORD');
    $today = date('YmdHis');
    $output_file = "{$db}_{$today}.sql.gz";
    if (!is_dir(storage_path('backups'))) mkdir(storage_path('backups'));
    $path = escapeshellarg(storage_path("backups/{$output_file}"));
    $process = new Process(
        sprintf(
            'mysqldump --routines=true --compact --comments=false -u%s -p%s %s |gzip > %s',
            escapeshellarg($DBUSER),
            escapeshellarg($DBPASSWD),
            $db,
            $path
        )
    );
    try {
        $process->run();
        if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                //$aws = resolve(S3Service::class);
                //$aws->upload($path, $output_file);
                Log::info("Daily Backup Successs {$path}");
            } else {
                echo "File Not Found: {$path} \n";
            }
        }
    } catch (ProcessFailedException $err) {
        Log::error('Daily Backup Failed', (array) $err);
    }
}
```

always getting File Not Found, but backup is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by just removing escapeshellarg() function from file path.
because of that function fopen was not able to read that path.

```
function db_backup($db)
{
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$DBUSER = env('DB_USERNAME');
$DBPASSWD = env('DB_PASSWORD');
$today = date('YmdHis');
$output_file = "{$db}_{$today}.sql.gz";
if (!is_dir(storage_path('backups'))) mkdir(storage_path('backups'));
$path = storage_path("backups/{$output_file}");
$process = new Process(
    sprintf(
        'mysqldump --routines=true --compact --comments=false -u%s -p%s %s |gzip > %s',
        escapeshellarg($DBUSER),
        escapeshellarg($DBPASSWD),
        $db,
        $path
    )
);
try {
    $process->run();
    if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            //$aws = resolve(S3Service::class);
            //$aws->upload($path, $output_file);
            Log::info("Daily Backup Successs {$path}");
        } else {
            echo "File Not Found: {$path} \n";
        }
    }
} catch (ProcessFailedException $err) {
    Log::error('Daily Backup Failed', (array) $err);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's Process() constructor takes an array, not a string. Here is some [useful examples in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#using-features-from-the-os-shell) that outlines the correct usage.

Luckily, there's a static helper [`Process::fromShellCommandline()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php#L189) that you can use to create your new Process object from a string command.

You can then amend your code to be something similar to:

```php
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline(sprintf(
'mysqldump --routines=true --compact --comments=false -u%s -p%s %s |gzip > %s',            escapeshellarg($DBUSER),
    escapeshellarg($DBPASSWD),
    $db,
    $path
));
```

The reason you're not getting any errors could be due to your error reporting. To prove this working I had to modify your script and ran the command `'echo "%s:%s %s" | gzip > %s',` instead so ymmv.

Comment: code is working fine only problen is that fopen not able to read that backup file created by Process.